# MSSQL - Date Range

Tags: sql-server, datetime, date-range

**Table1**

event1: Event 1 Name

event1_date: Date of Event

**Table2**

event2: Event 2 Name

event2_date: Date of Event

event1: Event 1 Name

I have tried several syntaxes found online, but none provide exactly what I need. In layman's terms, this is what I need:

*If an event in Table2 took place within 7 days of any event in Table1, then add the event's name in the event1 field.*

**Edited for Comments:**

*What have I tried, and why has it not worked?*
I have been trying to get this to work for five days. I don't know how many different syntaxes I have tried. At 3AM this morning I deleted all of my notes in a bit of rage, so I am not able to provide a list of what I have tried.

Small sample table is provided below.

Table1

| event1 | event1_date |
| --- | --- |
| Event 1 | 1/1/2020 |
| Event 2 | 1/15/2020 |
| Event 3 | 2/1/2020 |
| Event 4 | 2/20/2020 |

Table2

| event2 | event2_date | event1 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Event 2.1 | 1/10/2020 |  |
| Event 2.2 | 1/11/2020 |  |
| Event 2.3 | 1/16/2020 | Event 2 |
| Event 2.4 | 2/25/2020 | Event 4 |

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results (as text)

Comment: *"I have tried several syntaxes found online, but none provide exactly what I need."* And what were those attempts? Why didn't they work?

Comment: I edited the original post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seven days prior AND/OR seven days in the future of the event from table 1?

The dot notation in table 2, column event2 - is that needed and what needs to be done if there are more than one events within that time frame (another line, or build out event list in table 2, event 1 column?

**not at SQL box at the moment....   but this might help

```
SET NOCOUNT ON;  

DECLARE @event2_date   datetime
DECLARE @outtext       nvarchar(100)
DECLARE @prior7        datetime
DECLARE @after7        datetime

DECLARE event2_cursor CURSOR FOR SELECT event2_date FROM table2;

OPEN event2_cursor  

FETCH NEXT FROM event2_cursor INTO @event2_date  

  WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0  
    BEGIN  

  set @prior7 = dateadd(DD, -7, @event2_date);
  set @after7 = dateadd(DD, 7, @event2_date);

  set @outtext = select event1_text from table1 where event1_date 
  BETWEEN @prior7 AND @after7

  print @outtext

END   
CLOSE event2_cursor;  
DEALLOCATE event2_cursor;
```

Answer (score 0):

This should be possible with a single UPDATE statement containing a subquery. Example below.

Note 1: You might have more than one row in Table1 within 7 days from the row in Table2. I've dealt with this by ordering the duplicates by the date difference and putting in the first.

Note 2: DATEDIFF(day, x, y) gives a negative result if x is after y. If you only want values in the 7 days before or 7 days after rather than both you will need to set one of the values in the BETWEEN clause to 0.

```
set dateformat MDY;

create table Table1 
(
    event1 nvarchar(max),
    event1_date date
);

create table Table2 
(
    event2 nvarchar(max),
    event2_date date,
    event1 nvarchar(max)
);

insert into 
    Table1
values 
    ('Event 1', '1/1/2020'),
    ('Event 2', '1/15/2020'),
    ('Event 3', '2/1/2020'),
    ('Event 4', '2/20/2020');

select 
    *
from
    Table1;

insert into 
    Table2
values 
    ('Event 2.1', '1/10/2020', null),
    ('Event 2.2', '1/11/2020', null),
    ('Event 2.3', '1/16/2020', null),
    ('Event 2.4', '2/25/2020', null);

select
    *
from
    Table2;

update 
    Table2
set 
    event1 = (
        select top 1 
            Table1.event1
        from
            Table1
        WHERE
            DATEDIFF(day, Table1.event1_date, Table2.event2_date) between -7 and 7
        order by
            DATEDIFF(day, Table1.event1_date, Table2.event2_date)
    );

select 
    *
from
    Table2;
```